# What techniques to use to achieve similar look as attached photo

Tags: portrait

I've been really curious about how to get similar results as this photo:

[image]

I'm new to photography, but I'd be interested to know what sort of techniques are being used in taking these shots and in editing the photo.

Comment: Please describe the "look" or effect that you are wondering about in text as is suggested here: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/psa-on-whats-this-effect-questions

Comment: if you have the shots, how do you get them into this configuration? (3x2)

Answer (score 3):

Shoot with a bright white background, such as snow or sand. Have your subjects wear dark clothing. [Expose to the right](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/23010/9161), develop to the left, and desaturate. Adjust the skin tones to be slightly red.

Answer (score 1):

Low saturation, low white point that is crushed (highly compressed above a certain threshold brightness, only slightly though).  I'd probably start with about a 85% saturation, maybe 80% and drop the highlights part of the curve (in curves) significantly and fairly sharply for the top 15% to 20% or so.  There is still slight contrast in the whites to keep it from blowing, but there is no strong white.

Comment: " low white point that is crushed " - ?

Comment: @rapscalli - Like clipped, but some detail remains.  Bright white is a dim white, dim white is a slightly dimmer white.  It isn't clipped (a hard cut at max white value for the gamut of the image) but it is crushed (compressed down) to a much smaller set of values.  You here it more frequently when referring to compression in the audio world since over-compression is more commonly used there.