# Do some Olympus bodies compensate for effective macro aperture differently than others?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, macro, olympus, micro-four-thirds, effective-aperture

UPDATE: In the process of attempting some objective comparison between images from my camera and those helpfully submitted, I found that the exposure relationship between RAW and embedded preview isn't even consistent *from my own camera, with no change in settings, and no "magic" options enabled*. So, for now I consider the personal aspect of this question "on hold", but if anyone has experienced what I'm describing and can contribute an answer that would be *generally useful*, please do.

---

I've been using the [Oly 60mm f/2.8 macro](http://www.getolympus.com/us/en/lenses/m-zuiko-digital-ed-60mm-f2-8-macro.html) on an E-PL6 body which makes for a nice, compact rig that works great for my purposes. Oddly, though, the camera wants to compensate for the effective aperture of macro-range shooting with *in camera processing* instead of adjusting actual exposure, and this includes the preview (and as far as I can tell, the histogram).

Essentially, the RAW files that appeared to be [ETTR](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/23003/what-is-ettr-expose-to-the-right/) are actually underexposed. I can work around this by compensating manually, but it's not much fun to have to do this every time you change your working distance a little under awkward conditions with subjects that might vanish at any moment.

The other issue is that this process leaves me with disconcertingly blown-out preview images that are difficult to evaluate in-camera. My question, therefore, is whether this behavior is common to *all* Olympus bodies when using this lens, or if perhaps the higher-end models do things differently, so that I can take this into consideration when the time comes for the next purchase.

I'm hoping for responses based on actual experiences shooting RAW at 1:1 with this lens on Olympus bodies, since this type of information doesn't tend to be available in documentation or reviews. I'm not in the market for a Panasonic body, but would find information about that use case interesting, too.

And just for the record, all firmware is current, and yes, I've investigated *every single deeply-hidden menu option that could possibly relate to this*, and have the lens correction options that *are* presented turned off. I have a good understanding of the RAW development software that I use - *this is purely an issue of the camera trying to be "smart"* in a way that I consider really dumb (abusing all that lens-correction capability built into the Micro Four Thirds system) when shooting at distances where "effective aperture" is a significant factor.

All of that said, huge thanks to anybody who can provide the specific information requested! :)

Comment: I have an E-P5 and I also have this lens. There are no pictures online yet. Firmware 1.7 and I have a Metz Ringflash. What kind of sample picture would you like to see? I'm open for experiments. Not a specialized macro photographer.

Comment: @knb: If you would be willing to make available a RAW file taken at 1:1 magnification, it wouldn't really matter much what the subject was, as long as it allowed for evaluating the exposure of the embedded preview vs. the RAW data (the 2-stop difference is pretty obvious). If the E-P5 behavior turns out to be different from the E-PL6, it might make sense to start a community wiki answer where people could add the info for different models to a list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here on [google drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6iNkAyq3-jIaWhld0RnSnhpd1k) I have provided 5 images taken with an E-P5 ( Firmware 1.7), 60 mm 2.8 macro lens, and  a Metz Ringflash.

Right now it is night here in Europe, so I just took a few pictures of items on my desk in bad LED light and with the flash.

I am not sure what you are looking for (in the EXIF data ?); hope it helps nevertheless.

Comment: It might be better to take back-and-forth diagnostic work to [chat], and post an answer when you have a result.

Comment: @mattdm: Fair enough. I'll try to get a simple dcraw command line for generating a comparison into the question shortly, to make it easier for anyone to evaluate themselves.

Comment: @knb: The 1:1 close-up of the yellow label is just what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Making this the accepted answer for now, until I can can come up with a more methodical process for comparing results.

Comment: @junkyardsparkle Just for my curiosity, what's the punchline? Is it different?

Comment: @mattdm Well, it wouldn't be a very good punchline if it was that simple, right? ;) I found that the shared 1:1 image didn't display the disparity I was ranting about, but in the process I noticed that not *all* of mine, do, either, so... back down the rabbit hole I go. I'll overhaul the question if I can narrow down the steps to reproduce...